# php-fpm Reload Breaks up everything

Tags: php-fpm

I'm using

> PHP 7.0.3 FPM Service on Centos 7.2

I have currently **300 different FPM pool**s under 300 different users that all **runs with ondemand.**

The problem is when i add a new pool i have to reload the fpm service using

```
service php-fpm reload
```

However, when i run this, suddenly every current request on my Server is being dropped and Every request after that command, is not being processed (Nginx timeouts).

I have to write

```
service php-fpm restart
```

to get my service back with the new pool i added.

Why that is happening? I have to solve this immediately as when i create a new user, every other users gets nginx timeout until the service is restarted.

Why reload fails to add the new pool and why it hangs up the fpm service?

I searched the whole google for similar issues, but nothing is helpful for my solution.

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Your username fits my thoughts when I read you've got 300 separate FPM pools. Yowch.

Comment: :P. I run pools on different users for security.